# Conditional Formating with if then statement

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a workbook with 2 sheets, Sheet 1 has  Column I. Column I is filled with Percent's. I want these %'s formatted as black or red based on conditional formatting.

Sheet 2 has cell B2 filled in with one of the following "Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec."

The conditional Formatting formula I thought would be something along with lines of:

If(Sheet2 cell B2 = "Feb" then If the % in Sheet 1 Column I11-I31 the column is less than 10 divided by 12, color Red.

Then the same formula for each month but 9/12 for March and so on.

Hopefully this makes sense. I appreciate everyone taking a look.

Thank you, 
Matt

Answer (score 1):

The conditional formulas essentially already follows the IF logic, they are expecting a TRUE / FALSE response:

`AND(Sheet2!$B$2="Feb,$I11<(10/12))`

The conditional formatting will automatically increment the cell references based on the [absolute referencing](https://www.excel-easy.com/functions/cell-references.html#absolute-reference)

The IF Statement is null and void but if it helps you to understand, you would use it like so:

`IF(AND(Sheet2!$B$2="Feb,$I11<(10/12)),TRUE,FALSE)`

This will then return the TRUE / FALSE that the conditional formatting is expecting

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, Glitch_Doctor. The formula looks exactly like I am looking for. The conditional formatting takes the formula, but it doesn't turn the %'s red for me. Any ideas? Thank you, Matt